# running knex migrations on elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, knex.js

I just put my node.js project up on elastic beanstalk and it is configured properly.

I now have the application connected to my RDS postgres DB through the knex plugin.

Locally, to run a knex migration to update the local database, i would just run this in the console "knex migrate:latest" however that wont exactly work for elastic beanstalk because I can't run commands from inside the project folder(at least I don't think I can).

How do I run knex commands on my elastic beanstalk app?

bear in mind, I'm pretty green to elastic beanstalk.

Answer (score 3):

Elastic Beanstalk will run the `prestart` and `poststart` scripts in your package.json file.

```
{
    "name": "...",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "...",
    "scripts": {
        "prestart": "node ./node_modules/knex/lib/bin/cli.js migrate:latest",
        "poststart": "..."
    }
}
```

Or you can run the migrations in your code, before starting the server:

```
knex.migrate.latest([config])
```

Comment: Small change....the bin folder is not located in the lib directory (at least in my version of knex  0.15.2).  `"prestart": "node ./node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js migrate:latest",`

Comment: Can also just run `knex migrate:latest` without the node node_modules stuff. But is `prestart` the right place to do this? If there are table conflicts, the server will fail to start. Are you guys using `createTableIfNotExists`? It's said to be deprecated, so not sure how to handle tables that already exist.

Comment: Not ideal for muti-instance setup I guess

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an npm version greater than `5.2`. It normally comes with an `npx` package that enables you to run scripts/libraries from your local project `node modules` rather than the globally installed one. This makes it easy to run `knex` from your project directory directly. There will be no need to having to install the knex package globally in your preinstall scripts. You could simply have a node command script like so:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "npx knex migrate:latest && node server.js"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After many hours of searching through outdated SO answers, here's my working setup:

.ebextensions/01-migrate-db.config

```
container_commands:
  01_node_binary:
    command: "ln -sf `ls -td /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-* | head -1`/bin/node /bin/node"
    leader_only: true
  02_npm_binary:
    command: "ln -sf `ls -td /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-* | head -1`/bin/npm /bin/npm"
    leader_only: true
  03_migrate_db:
    command: "sudo DB_HOST=${DB_HOST} DB_PORT=${DB_PORT} DB_NAME=${DB_NAME} DB_USER=${DB_USER} DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD} npm run db:migration:run"
    leader_only: true
```

package.json

```
...
scripts: {
  "db:migration:run": "knex migrate:latest"
}
```